# Duplicate url_title will not display content after appending number

Tags: url, import, datagrab, duplicate

I’m using datagrab to parse an xml feed with non unique titles. eg. every week I will get a feed with a sports result where the title will be Division 1: Results Round Up with the url_title becoming division-1-results-round-up which displays correctly in the browser mysite.com/division-1-results-round-up

The next time the import is run I will get another story with the title Division 1: Results Round Up which its url_title then becomes division-1-results-round-up1 and the story is not displayed in the browser

mysite.com/division-1-results-round-up1

Over the course of a season I will have a lot of Results round up storys which will not be displayed.

I’ve tried using other fields like story id or story intro as the url_title but it doesnt work either.

thanks in advance for your help

alan

Comment: You append a number to your URL, but is it also added to the url_title variable? Else show a list with all your enties and echo its url_title to see what the url_title really is!

Comment: thanks for the reply. does the url_title have to match the title (without the dashes between words) ? When I edit the story under Content->Edit the url_title has automatically had the number appended to the url_title. Are you suggesting that it will be different ?

Comment: No, the url_title can be different from the title. But you must use the url_title in your UTL that belongs to the entry to get that entry. I don't know the add-on datagrabb, but the generated url_title should be unique. That's why you get numbers in the url_title when adding an entry with the same title. Hope this helps you!

Comment: it does indeed...i guess its irrelevant whether the url_title is generated by datagrab or not, my story is not being displayed when a number is appended (delete the number and the correct story is displayed)